# Ruby On Rails ljust(5,'.') does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string

I'm trying to left justify a string in a rails view with a pad character.

The following doesn't work:

```
<%= menu_items.description.ljust(5,".")%>
```

Neither does this:

```
<%= menu_items.description.to_s.ljust(5,".")%>
```

Just to mess around and try to get something I found the following works.

```
<%= menu_items.description.length.to_s.ljust(5,".")%>
```

It prints out the length converted to a string and appends the pad characters.  What gives? How do I make the first snippet work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works because .length gives you a number, probably zero, and then adds ....

```
<%= menu_items.description.length.to_s.ljust(5,".")%>
```

What do you get when you just do this:

```
<%= menu_items.description %>
```

Look like menu_items is an array. Try this

```
<% menu_items.each do |menu_item| %>
  <%= menu_item.description.ljust(5,".") %>
<% end %>
```

Also, if it is not an array, then the .. will be appended to make it a total length of 5. If description is longer, it will do nothing.

Comment: Yeah, menu_items is an array and I iterated exactly as shown.  It turns out the second part of your answer is correct,  when I bump the ljust to 100 I get the result I want.  Is there a method I can use to append a character after the description?d

Comment: The number of characters will depend on how long the description string will be.  The shorter the description the more pad characters I'll need and vice versa.

Comment: Sure: Try menu_item.description + ("X" * n_times) where X is the character and n_times is the number of characters you want to add.